# Angular can not initialize variable

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I have `get` a method who returns the data who is type `ProductModel`.

```
 getProduct(id:number): Observable<ProductModel[]> {

    const url = `${'api/product/getProductById/'}/${id}`;

    return this.http.get<ProductModel[]>(url).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
    )
  }
```

I return single `ProductModel` and it is not necessary to have a list of `ProductModel`. How to do that, when I remove `[]` I have error?
And I have a problem in my component, I declared the   `product :ProductModel ;` and when return the data my `product` is undefined

```
this.productService.getProduct(162).subscribe((product) => {
      this.product = product[0];
    console.log(product)
    })
```

Comment: @Sln san sun this is because of array return value in backend I think.

Comment: To fix it you should change backend

Comment: Are you saying that the API returns an array only when there's more than one ProductModel, otherwise when there's a single match, it returns a single ProductModel which is not inside an array?

Comment: Yes, my bucket returns single match and that I want to store in a variable.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem with `this.handleError('getProduct', [])`

Comment: I would change the implementation of the API if the Id is a unique value for a product. If it's not unique and there *could* be more than one, always consume an array in the UI as a single element in an array is a valid state.

Answer (score 0):

If your API return an array with an ony element, I'll change the service using "map" to return an Object

```
getProduct(id:number): Observable<ProductModel> {
    const url = `${'api/product/getProductById/'}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<ProductModel[]>(url).pipe(
      map((res:any[])=>res[0]),
      catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
    )
  }
```

I don't know about your this.handleError function, I supouse you can always use some like

```
handleError(function:string:data:any)
{
   if (Array.isArray(data))
   {
       ...data is an array...
   }
   else
   {
       ..data is a object...
   }
}
```